# How to store data based on what we choose ? with this code the data i get always "Kuta"

Tags: firebase, react-native

How to store data based on what we choose ? with this code the data i get always "Kuta"

```
        
                     <View>
                        <Picker
                            selectedValue={this.state.budget}
                            onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => 
                            this.setState({budget:itemValue})}
                            value={this.state.budget}
                        >
                            <Picker.Item label="Jimbaran" value={this.state.budget = "Jimbaran"} />
                            <Picker.Item label="Kuta" value={this.state.budget = "Kuta"} />

                        </Picker>
                    </View>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's some problems here. First, the value prop of Picker.Item is the value who will be sent to the Picker parent.

Second, `this.state.budget = "Kuta"` is an attempt to directly assign a value to your state, wich is a basic violation of React rules. **States are immutables !!**

[Quick explanation](https://flaviocopes.com/react-immutability/)

So you're code should looks like this

```
<View>
    <Picker
        selectedValue={this.state.budget}
        onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {
            this.setState({budget:itemValue})
        }}
    >
        <Picker.Item label="Jimbaran" value="Jimbaran" />
        <Picker.Item label="Kuta" value="Kuta" />
    </Picker>
</View>
```

[Picker docs](https://github.com/react-native-picker/picker)

Comment: Mark as resolved if that answer your question